# Margin from last div and last column

Tags: html, css

How to take a `margin` from the last div of each column, and to margin all the divs of the last column

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.teste {
  margin: 135px auto 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px dashed #000
}

div.teste>h3 {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed #000
}

div.teste>div {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  width: 65px !important;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

div.teste>div:nth-child( 4n-1) {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ccc
}

div.teste>div:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="teste">
  <h3>Primeiro</h3>

  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>

</div>
```

the expected result would be this
[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest to use **[`Flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)** layout here. Wrap your all numbers div and apply `display: flex` using `width`.

Also you will need to play with parent div `padding` and child divs `margin` to properly align the divs.

```css
h3 {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed #000
}

div.teste>div {
  width: calc(33.333% - 10px);
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.teste {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  padding: 15px 15px 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<h3>Primeiro</h3>
<div class="teste">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>
```

---

Another solution is try to use margin on the child div and remove margin from every (3n+1) child using `nth-child` selector. This solution will work for both cases odd/even

```css
h3 {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed #000
}

div.teste>div {
  width: calc(33.333% - 10px);
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.teste {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  padding: 15px 15px 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div.teste>div:nth-child(3n+1) {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<h3>Primeiro</h3>
<div class="teste">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how to get div aligned if the number is odd? I think space-between is the problem http://prntscr.com/pqy8nz 
(11 side by side 10)

Comment: @mehid I will suggest you to edit your question with proper explanation about the issue because you haven't mentioned anything about the odd or even numbers of divs. BTW I have added another solution using margin for the odd numbers of divs. You can use it for both odd/even.

Comment: resolved using `display: grid` via the link you sent